# Making enumerated lists during for loop

Tags: python

I would like to generate lists whose names include the iterator.
Something like:

```
 for i in range(3):
     list_{here is the number}=[i,i+2,i+10]
```

The desired output:

```
>>list_0
[0,2,10]
>>list_1
[1,3,11]
>>list_2
[2,4,12]
```

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 1):

Look into dictionary comprehension:

```
result = {f'list_{i}': [i, i + 2, i + 10] for i in range(3)}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was thinking about dictionaries, but is there a way to do it with the lists? I need lists as I work further with the indexes, which makes it cumbersome in case of dictionaries.

Comment: What do you mean by lists? The other answer generates a list. You can iterate over a dictionary as well. This generates a dictionary where each key points to a list.

Comment: I mean you propose to generate a dictionary with the desired names as keys, while I am trying to generate, if possible, just the three single lists

Comment: Thats exactly what the answer below does.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
[[i,i+2,i+10] for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: I did not downvote; but I think it is because, OP wants variables (with names) to be like `list_{index}`, but your answer just provides a single nested list.

Comment: @mshsayem It must have been more than that because who ever downvoted did it to both answers. I assume it was one of those, its a duplicate so don't answer downvotes.